# Is this space Dense in $ C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the space $\{f\in C[0,1]\mid \int_0^1f\neq 0\}$ dense in $C[0,1]$ with sup-norm topology.

I think yes, because it is the inverse image of the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks, the answer by Jorge is also great.

Comment: In fact my comment was wrong. A correct related argument would be that your set is the complement of a closed hyperplane. This is always dense in any Banach space, but a direct proof such as Jorge's is probably better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call that set $A$, we shall prove it is a dense set.

Pick $f\not \in A$, in other words $f$ such that $\int\limits_{0}^1 f=0$, and pick $\epsilon >0$.

Notice that the function $g(x)=f(x)+\epsilon/2$ is in $A$ and its distance from $f$ is $\epsilon/2$, so the set is in fact dense.

Comment: is the set connected also?

Comment: nope, the continuous functions with positive integral form an open subset, and so do the ones with negative integral.

Comment: For $C([0,1],\mathbb C)$ the situation is different though.

Comment: yes, for the connectedness part.